# How to configure integration tests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, integration-testing, spock, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (packed to classic WAR without SpringBoot runner) and I'd like to implement integration tests in Spock. When I use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MySpringConfiguration.class)` then only "standard" Spring context is used (without any benefits from Boot, like for example `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
class FooSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private CustomProperties customProperties;

    def "should read spring boot properties"() {

        when:
            def foo = customProperties.foo;
        then:
            foo
    }

}
```

I love Spock!

### Update

As @gilad said, this is not needed in [Spring Boot 1.3+](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-spock)

Comment: Maybe you should amend your answer to use that instead of `@ContextConfiguration` then?

Comment: @Dave I have `NullPointerException` on `customProperties` with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't really know anything about Spock, so I don't know how it implements Spring integration. I assume maybe something has to change there as well (maybe they don't know about Spring meta-annotations yet)?

Comment: @Dave This is possible, `spock-spring` is old project ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44974/discussion-between-mariuszs-and-dave-syer)

Comment: According to the Spring Boot documentation on [testing with Spock](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-spock), `@ContextConfiguration` must be used instead of `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Comment: It also says that you need to add the `spock-spring` dependency

Comment: @SpringApplicationConfiguration can now be used following a fix in Spock. The comment Paul is referring to will be removed in Spring Boot 1.3.0: [**latest** testing with Spock](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-spock)